# get tweets from tweeter to android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity

Good day guys, I just want to ask if there is a possible way to get tweets from Twitter and then throw it to a project in  android studio? If its possible can anyone tell me how? thesis purposes. thank you very much

Comment: You question is not proper and tags are not related to your query. Please read this first https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

**You can get the tweets of a particular user from Twitter API but no one is gonna throw it to a project in the android studio.**

You will have to make the Android project and hit the API with the required authentication params and then it will give you the tweets of a user.

To know more about the API and AUTH params visit the following links:

1. [Get Tweet timelines - developer.twitter.com](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline.html)
2. [Android, getting new tweets from specific users](https://twittercommunity.com/t/android-getting-new-tweets-from-specific-users/60570)
3. [Show Tweets - Github](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android/wiki/Show-Tweets)

Sample project to get user tweets:

1. [How can get the twitter tweets in android list view from a twitter public page](https://androidexample.com/How_can_get_the_twitter_tweets_in_android_list_view_from_a_twitter_public_page(ie_wwwtwittercom/givecentral)_Someone_help_me_with_the_working_code_please_I_have_searched_all_the_websites_but_not_getting_any_solution/question_answer.php?view=qad&token=119)
2. [Show user tweets.](http://www.androhub.com/android-twitter-show-timelines/)

Hope this helps.